# iPhone: How to create a iPhone application which gets automatically invoked at a particular time

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create a iPhone App which gets invoked automatically at a particular interval.
Regards

Comment: you mean you want to make a background application which runs at background, like Alarm in iPhone?

Answer (score 4):

You can't. (At least, not on non-jailbroken phones.) Best you can do is send the user a push notification, and give them the *option* of running your app in response.